# Read UTF-8 in Perl and output as ISO-8859-1

Tags: perl, file-io, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have to read a text file in Perl which is encoded as UTF-8, this is working fine. My output file OUT_2 has to be encoded as ISO-8859-1 (aka "Latin1"). I tried this code (and some more) but my output file OUT_2 is always written as UTF-8. Any idea to achieve it?

```
use strict;
use Encode::Encoder;

open IN, "c:/Temp/Input.txt"; # this file is UTF-8

open OUT_1, ">", "c:/Temp/out_1.txt"; 
# encoding of OUT_1 does not matter because it contains only ASCII
open OUT_2, ">:encoding(latin1)", "c:/Temp/out_2.txt"; 

my $line = 1;
while ( <IN> ) {
    chomp;
    print OUT_1 "Write line $line\n";
    print OUT_2 "$_ and some stuff\n";
    $line++;
}

close IN;
close OUT_1;
close OUT_2;
```

This proposal does not work either:

```
 my $data = "$_ and some stuff\n";
 Encode::encode("latin1", Encode::decode("UTF-8", $data));
 print OUT_2 $data;
```

Comment: Does your input have non-ASCII characters in it?

Comment: Yes, but all fit into ISO-8859-1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work correctly (see the description of Perl's [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) function; there is no need to explicitly transform the Perl string on the octet level using [encode/decode](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html)) (further afield, possibly see the description of the [open pragma](https://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) and the [binmode](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) function):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in,  '<:encoding(UTF-8)',  'input-file-name'  or die $!;
open my $out, '>:encoding(latin1)', 'output-file-name' or die $!;

while (<$in>) {
  print $out $_;
}
```

The only substantive difference from your code is that I am explicitly decoding the incoming data from UTF8 bytes to characters.

What are you doing to find out what the encodings of your input and output files are? I've used `file`.

```
$ file input-file-name output-file-name
input-file-name: UTF-8 Unicode text
output-file-name:  ISO-8859 text
```

And also `od -ch`:

```
$ od -ch input-file-name
0000000   a   a   a 302 243 302 243 302 243   z   z   z  \n
           6161    c261    c2a3    c2a3    7aa3    7a7a    000a
0000015

$ od -ch output-file-name
0000000   a   a   a 243 243 243   z   z   z  \n
           6161    a361    a3a3    7a7a    0a7a
0000012
```

(My file contained "aaa£££zzz".)

Comment: I never use perl before so I wonder in your script, where should I put the name of file that I want to convert ?

Comment: @zwlayer: I've updated my answer in a way that (hopefully) makes it clearer.

Comment: thank you so much. I got  it now. Hopefully one day, some guy will come up and make an interpreter for the ones who want to use perl snippets without knowing even how to read perl : )

Comment: @zwlayer: I really hope not. You get far better programs when people actually take the time to understand the code they're writing :-)

Comment: I agree with you when the PL is not perl :) I bet perl is not  designed to be read but instead just write.

Comment: @zwlayer: Well, you're wrong there. And adding a smiley to an unfunny comment doesn't magically make it funny.

Comment: Even though I don't want to turn this into a discussion, I believe I should say that labeling statements with some tags like "funny" or "unfunny" is not a rational thing since these are subjective categories.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for `Encode::encode($encoding_out, Encode::decode($encoding_in, $data));` where `$encoding_in` and `$encoding_out` in your case would be UTF-8 and Latin1 (iso-8859-1) respectively.

If you have non-printable characters in UTF-8, lossless conversion will be impossible given that the set of possible characters in UTF-8 is bigger than the set of possible characters in Latin-1. Any characters that don't translate will be substituted with '?'.